# angular ng-multiselect-dropdown get id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i'm using ng-multiselect to choose items from an api thats works fine but when i click on submit im getting an array that looks like this
0: {item_id: 111, item_text: "some text"}
1: {item_id: 222, item_text: "some text2"}

how can i only get the value of the item_id in a string like this
item_id : 111,222

```
export class ExampleListComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input()
  get value(): any { return this._value; }
  set value(value: any) { this.writeValue(value); }
  private _value: any = null;

  public loading = false;
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ExampleListItem>();
  dropdownSettings: IDropdownSettings;
  dropdownList = [];
  selectedItems = [];
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<any>();

  onChange: Function = () => {};
  onTouched: Function = () => {};


  constructor(
    private exListService: exListService,
  ) { }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();

    this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: 'item_id',
      textField: 'item_text',
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      itemsShowLimit: 3,
      allowSearchFilter: true
    };
  }

registerOnChange(onChange: Function) {
    this.onChange = onChange;
}

registerOnTouched(onTouched: Function) {
    this.onTouched = onTouched();
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== this._value) {
      this._value = value;

      this.onChange(value);
      this.onTouched();
      this.valueChange.emit(value);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
   this.onChange(value);
   this.valueChange.emit(value);
```

to:

```
   const valueToOutput = (value ?? []).map(valueObject => valueObject.item_id).join(',')

   this.onChange(valueToOutput);
   this.valueChange.emit(valueToOutput);
```

Note, this will give you a blank string `""` if `value` is undefined, null or an empty array.

Comment: Good to hear. :)